# Extract the last part of URL path with Custom JS - but not added parameters with?

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I am trying to extract the last part of a URL to track in GTM, but not include added parameters like "?gclid=...".
As in:
https://example.com/m/5f5a0a9472cf844b320b6136/?gclid=1234
I want to just extract the **5f5a0a9472cf844b320b6136**.
So far I've used:

```
function() {
var pageUrl = window.location.href;
return pageUrl.split("/")[pageUrl.split("/").length - 1];
}
```

But that is giving me the gclid number. This issue is, that parameter only exists on the *landing page*, not subsequent pages.
so if I were to use `length - 2]` that won't work once they leave the landing page. It would return the /m/.
How do I escape the "?" string on the landing page?

Comment: Thanks for all of the suggestions. I have found mixed success, and I think I understand why. First, a clarification. The landing page is a dynamic number unique to the session (the 5f5a0...6136). So it won't be the same for every visit.

Comment: Secondly, the landing page has a trailing slash. This is throwing off the ```pop()``` and the ```length - 1``` for the first page, but the code works on subsequent pages which do NOT have a trailing slash. I think the *pathname* option would work, but need to account for that trailing slash.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this which will be easier

```
function (){
  paths = window.location.pathname.split("/")
  return paths[paths.length-1]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help

```js
const strs = [
  "https://example.com/5f5a0a9472cf844b320b6136/?gclid=1234/",
  "https://example.com/m/5f5a0a9472cf844b320b6136/?gclid=1234/",
  "https://example.com/m/n/5f5a0a9472cf844b320b6136/",
  "https://example.com/m/n/5f5a0a9472cf844b320b6136",
];

strs.forEach((str) => {

  // ********************
  if (str.includes("?")) {
    const parts = str.split("/?")[0].split("/");
    console.log(parts[parts.length - 1]);
  } else {
    const lastChar = str.charAt(str.length - 1);
    str = lastChar === "/" ? str.substring(0, str.length - 1) : str;
    const parts = str.split("/");
    console.log(parts[parts.length - 1]);
  }
  // ********************
  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your using GTM, enable and use the built-in "page path" variable instead, which does not include parameters:

```
function() {
    return {{Page Path}}.split("/").pop();
}
```

`pop()` return the last element from the array (it also removes it from the array, which in this case does not matter).

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found an alternative solution that I thought I'd share. Because that variable string always totals 24 characters, I created a function to look for it.

```
    function getQuoteId() {
    var segments = window.location.pathname.split('/');
    for (var i = segments.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (segments[i] && segments[i].length === 24) {
            return segments[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

This mitigates the trailing "/" as well as the added parameters, and it returns the path I was looking to isolate.